# Need help and suggestion to create a complicated table positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-table

I want to create a simple table but yet it is very complicated in positioning. I don't have idea of how to manage it.

So I need to fetched the data from an API via Ajax JSON. Then arrange it to be like this:

[image]

The problem is, there are 3 JSON,

1. first is for the User Quantity
2. second is for Packet name (i.e POS 2 x 1 jam 3 bulan, inventory 3 x 1 jam 3 bulan, and so on)
3. third and the last are for the price

this is example of my JSON and its format:

User Quantity :

```
  [[{"id":1,"user_qty":1},
    {"id":2,"user_qty":2},
    {"id":3,"user_qty":5},
    {"id":4,"user_qty":30}]]
```

Packet Name :

```
 [[{"id":1,"name":"POS","training":"2 x 1 Jam","maintenance":"3 Bulan"},
    {"id":2,"name":"INVENTORY","training":"3 x 1 Jam","maintenance":"3 Bulan"},
    {"id":3,"name":"POS PLATINUM","training":"3 x 1.5 Jam","maintenance":"3 Bulan"},
    {"id":4,"name":"STANDARD","training":"4 x 1.5 Jam","maintenance":"3 Bulan"}]]
```

Price

```
 [[{"id":1,"packet_id":1,"user_qty_id":1,"harga":"2300000"},
    {"id":2,"packet_id":1,"user_qty_id":2,"harga":"3000000"},
    {"id":3,"packet_id":1,"user_qty_id":3,"harga":"4000000"},
    {"id":4,"packet_id":1,"user_qty_id":4,"harga":"6000000"},
    {"id":5,"packet_id":2,"user_qty_id":1,"harga":"4100000"},
    {"id":6,"packet_id":2,"user_qty_id":2,"harga":"5200000"},
    {"id":7,"packet_id":2,"user_qty_id":3,"harga":"6200000"},
    {"id":8,"packet_id":2,"user_qty_id":4,"harga":"8200000"},
    ]]
```

Can anyone help me on how to arrange them? Just comment if you are confused or have other opinions or ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: If you tried with any code means, just share it...

Comment: short answer: Convert json into js objects, map the main object, create a new object which combines all other objects, render a table with document.createElement or jQuery.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar sorry, but i doesn't get what you mean.

Comment: @lumio sorry, but can you explain it step by step for me ? im new in javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

something like this you meant?

```css
table {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
  border-collapse:separete;
}
td {padding:10px;}
.trTop td:last-child {text-align:right;}
.trBot td {text-align:right;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1 user</th>
    <th>2 user</th>
    <th>5 user</th>
    <th>30 user</th>  
  </tr>
  <tr class="trTop">
    <td colspan="2">Accounting platnum</td>
    <td colspan="2">2 x 1 jam 3 bulan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trBot">
    <td>9.000.000.000</td>
    <td>19.000.000.000</td>
    <td>29.000.000.000</td>
    <td>39.000.000.000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trTop">
    <td colspan="2">Accounting platnum</td>
    <td colspan="2">2 x 1 jam 3 bulan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trBot">
    <td>9.000.000.000</td>
    <td>19.000.000.000</td>
    <td>29.000.000.000</td>
    <td>39.000.000.000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trTop">
    <td colspan="2">Accounting platnum</td>
    <td colspan="2">2 x 1 jam 3 bulan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trBot">
    <td>9.000.000.000</td>
    <td>19.000.000.000</td>
    <td>29.000.000.000</td>
    <td>39.000.000.000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i want, but i still doesn't get it how to make it arrange automatically when i fetched data from json :/